# Data is not storing in django database

Tags: python, django, django-views

This is the code in views.py.

```
def thanks(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone= request.POST['phone']
        doctor = request.POST['doctor']
        msg = request.POST['reason']
        print(name, email, phone, msg)
        appointment_db = appointment(name=name, email=email, phone=phone, doctor=doctor, message=msg)
        appointment_db.save()
    return render(request, "thanks.html", {"name": name})
```

rest of the code is working. the only error is in the second-last and third-last line.

```
 appointment_db = appointment(name=name, email=email, phone=phone, doctor=doctor, message=msg)
        appointment_db.save()
```

this is the error:

```
                 appointment_db = appointment(email=email, phone=phone, doctor=doctor, message=msg)
TypeError: appointment() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

this is the model:

from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.
class appointment(models.Model):
    count=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email= models.EmailField(max_length=1000)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    message =models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    doctor = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " | "+ "Doctor : "+ self.doctor
```

The model is also registered and it is showing in the admin panel. However, when I try to store data in it via forms, it throws an error.

Comment: Show your `appointment` model

Comment: Edit original question. This is not readable

Comment: added model in question

Comment: @BartoszStasiak: no migrations actually do not matter in terms of constructor signature: if the migrations are "behind", then eventually it *will* go wrong, but Django does not check migrations, it simply constructs an SQL query that will of course fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you have a view function with the same name. This thus means that if you call `appointment(…)`, it triggers the view instead.

This is one of the reasons why classes are normally written in *PascalCase*, so `Appointment` instead of <s>`appointment`</s>:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    count = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # …
```

then the view thus works with:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST


@require_POST
def thanks(request):
    name = request.POST['name']
    email = request.POST['email']
    phone = request.POST['phone']
    doctor = request.POST['doctor']
    msg = request.POST['reason']
    print(name, email, phone, msg)
    Appointment.objects.create(
        name=name, email=email, phone=phone, doctor=doctor, message=msg
    )
    return render(request, 'thanks.html', {'name': name})
```

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: from .models import appointment
ImportError: cannot import name 'appointment' from 'hospitalApp.models'

Comment: now this error.

Comment: @AbdulMoizShah: you need to rename the import as well...